# how to save "order by" table?

Tags: java, sql-order-by, derby

I want to sort my database, then save it as it is.
what is the easiest way to do this?
sql can be something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM APP." + tablename + " order by" + sql_part;
```

thanks.

Comment: do you mean save the result set of the above query with order by on a table ?

Comment: hi @GopiKolla . yes. I want save above resultset on itself. (but sort it first)

Comment: if by "on itself" you mean to the same table, then i don't think it is possible - unless you do something like 1) using CTAS (Create Table As Select) and store the ordered resultset to a temp table, 2) drop your main table and 3) rename temp table to main table.

Comment: could you please provide codes to doing these if no other one provide easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow the below steps

```
 1) create table <temp_tablename> as SELECT * FROM APP.<tablename> order by <columnname>;
 2) drop table APP.<tablename>;
 3) ALTER TABLE <temp_tablename> RENAME TO APP.<tablename>; -- Oracle
    or RENAME TABLE <temp_tablename> TO APP.<tablename>; -- DB2
```